# Xcode issue with C++ Destructor in classes

Tags: c++, xcode, constructor, destructor

Im still learning c++ and im now trying to understand Constructors and Destructors.

I just keep getting the below error whenever i use Constructors and Destructors.
in my class.

> test(32992,0x100394380) malloc: *** error for object 0x100707010:
>   pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug (lldb)

although i can remove the error by just deleting the Destructor, but i know this is not a good programming because i have to free the memory.

this is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class student{
private:
    int *age, *mark1,*mark2,*mark3;
    string *name;

public:
    friend float avg(student);
    student(){
        age = new int;
        mark1 = new int;
        mark2 = new int;
        mark3 = new int;
        name = new string;

        cout << "Enter student name: "; cin >> *name;
        cout << "Enter student age: "; cin >> *age;
        cout << "Enter student 3 marks: "; cin >> *mark1 >> *mark2 >> *mark3;
        cout << endl; }

    ~student(){
        delete age;
        delete mark1;
        delete mark2;
        delete mark3;
        delete name; }

    string returnName(){
        return *name; }
};

float avg(student s){
    return (double)(*s.mark1+*s.mark2+*s.mark3)/3;}




int main() {

    student s[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        s[i];
        cout << "Avg of student " << s[i].returnName() << " is " << avg(s[i]) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). Have members of types `int` and `string` - you don't need pointers here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik .. Great to know about the Rule of three.. Thank you, i did not know this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing an argument **by value** to `avg()`. Your example calls two different things `s`, so I'll try to distinguish them by calling them `s_main` and `s_avg`.

When you pass an argument by value, C++ copies the data in `s_main` to `s_avg`. This is done via a **copy constructor**. You can specify your own copy constructor, but when you don't the compiler supplies one for you. The default copy constructor just copies the data over; in your case, `student` consists of pointers, so the default copy constructor copies the pointers. **It does not copy the data the pointers point to.**

Because `s_avg` is local to `avg()`, `avg` has to destroy `s_avg` when it returns. Hence, `avg()` calls `student`'s destructor on `s_avg` at the end of line 37. Practically speaking, that means the `avg()` deletes the pointers in `s_main[0]` and `s_main[1]` when it returns.

That sets up the problem for `main()`. Because `s_main[0]` and `s_main[1]` are local to `main()`, `main` has to destroy `s_main[0]` and `s_main[1]` when it returns. Hence, `main()` calls `student`'s destructor on `s_main[0]` and `s_main[1]` at the end of line 47. As before, the destructor tries to delete the pointers in both `s_main[0]` and `s_main[1]` -- but they have already been deleted! Hence your problem.

There are several ways to fix this. One is to observe Igor's advice: you don't really need pointers here. However, I can imagine that maybe you need pointers for a practical scenario as opposed to this toy scenario. In that case, another way to take care of this is to pass the argument to `avg()` **by reference**. This is really the proper way to pass arguments in C++ most of the time, anyway: you don't have to worry about a copy constructor or any of those weird things that C++ specializes in. To be precise, you should change line 12 so that it reads

```
friend float avg(student &);
```

and then change line 28 so that it reads

```
float avg(student & s){
```

and then it will work just fine.

Strictly speaking though, you should use a **constant** reference, unless you plan to modify the data somehow (which can happen). In this case, change line 12 to

```
friend float avg(const student &);
```

and line 28 to

```
float avg(const student & s){
```

and, again, it will work like a charm.

But really, Igor's right. Modern C++ is designed to help you avoid pointers, precisely because tracking them is so difficult, and the consequences of a mistake are so dangerous. Passing by reference is a good example of this. So avoid pointers unless you absolutely have to use them.